# Use a font family which has an actual italic variant (instead of oblique)

Tags: discussion, design

In the new design there was a change to the CSS that determines the fonts used for posts. This is what it is using now, based on my research:

> `font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;`

Overall I think it looks great, but there is a bit of an eyesore (in my opinion) when text is formatted as italic, which is really an "oblique" rather than italic.

For those unfamiliar with the difference: [TypeTalk: italic vs. oblique](http://creativepro.com/typetalk-italic-vs-oblique/) and this example:

[image: italic-oblique2]

Which looks like this:

> AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz
>   *AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz*

Here is an image version where I added some slant lines to illustrate:

[image: slant]

Which usually looks OK, at least by itself; but when used mid-paragraph, it can look really weird, especially on words than are oblique and end with a tall letter.

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur *adipiscing* elit, sed do eiusmod *tempor incididunt ut* labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris *nisi* ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. **Duis aute irure dolor *in reprehenderit* in voluptate** velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat ***cupidatat* non proident**, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Here is an image where we can see this clearly. To me it just looks tacky and would be better serve by a true italic rather than an oblique. Thoughts?

[image: slant_lorem]

Comment: Wait, there's a difference between *italic* and *oblique*? What would *oblique* look like?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, see [TypeTalk: italic vs. oblique](http://creativepro.com/typetalk-italic-vs-oblique/). Basically, italic is normally stylized, while oblique is not.

Comment: I made a simple [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3DP7Z.png) of roman, oblique and italic fonts, for another example of the differences. As I find it hard to see the difference between roman and oblique fonts +1.

Comment: @JoeWallis thanks a lot, I inserted the example into the post :-)

Comment: The CSS applied to your example sections *specifies italic already*. What you are asking for is not "use italic rather than oblique", but "use a font family which has an actual italic variant". Helvetica Neue, at least the version I have, claims to have italic, but is not particularly distinct from oblique. (And perhaps it would help if your italic-vs-oblique example was a *sans-serif* example.)

Comment: @KevinReid I attached a different screenshot to reflect this better, and changed the title accordingly. Thanks for the clarifications.